# Macrodroid -- stop loop when screen touched

Tags: macrodroid

Macrodroid question.

I have the following macro, which needs to loop:

1. UI Interaction
2. Wait 1 second
3. UI Interaction
4. Wait 2 seconds
5. Macro Run [This Macro]

How can I break the loop between Step 4 and Step 5 (Macro Run), if the screen is tapped, during that 2-second delay?

I have considered creating a second macro, that will terminate the first macro, upon trigger of screen tap, but screen tap is not a UI Interaction option as a trigger for the second macro.

Comment: @beeshyams  thank you, I'm not clear on your suggestion. In Dev Options I have Show Touches (show visual feedback when screen is touched) and Show Touch Data (touch data is visible on screen).  I'm not clear how a recording of a touch could be a trigger, though.  I need the trigger (to stop the loop) to be the actual touch I make, on a random place on the screen.

Comment: Like I said, it was  just a guess and probably wrong. What I thought was it could be somehow recorded and would work as trigger, which clearly is not the case. Sorry for suggesting without trying it